# Maven Run particular test with category and profile dosnt use the groups tag

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-profiles

I am working with maven and Junit at my project.
i would like to use a profile to run specific tests:

i have found this [guide](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/running-categorized-tests-using-junit-maven-and-annotated-test-suites/#JUnit_Test_Categories):

i have 2 profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>fastTests</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                   <groups>example.com.FastHolder</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
 <id>devProfile</id>
 <activation>
 <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault></activation>
<build>
```

ant the `@Test` class looks like that:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Category(FastHolderHolder.class)
public class FastHolderTest {
   /// some code
@Test
public void testIt() throws Exception {
}
}
```

While running this command `mvn test`

i would expect to have the maven run the test FastHolderTest
but it didn't:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ core ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

what should i validate to find out why it didn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've made at least a spelling mistake - your class in the @Category annotation reads **FastHolderHolder**, and **FastHolder** in the POM.